# Only one object (cube with background image) is rendering after 1st frame

Tags: rendering, keyframes

Preview render shows all objects properly. When I go to render as animation using PNGs, all objects besides one cube disappear for the rest of the scene. The cube has an image on one face and is used as a background for the scene. Why do all of my objects disappear after one frame?

My blend file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33273

First frame of scene
[image: First frame of scene]

Second frame of scene
[image: Second frame of scene]

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 2):

After getting some mixed results it would appear that the issue is a bad rigid body cache.

Open the file and set the current frame to a negative value (-5 works) then play the animation all the way through to rebuild the rigid body cache, then render.

Answer (score 2):

Did some digging on other boards, found a solution that took care of the issue. Pressing CTRL+N calculated normals and fixed the problem. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

May be the motion blur bug with rigid bodies -that seems to be fixed now- so try a recent build..? 
see here > https://developer.blender.org/T40017

Comment: This only applies to cycles, but it appears that the OP is using BI.

Comment: @gandalf3 dingto commented that that bug is not cycles only and it appears it might be close to that issue if not the same.